# Modify Points of a Multires Modifier through Python

Tags: python, multiresolution

Is it possible to modify points of a Multires Modifier through Python? I can get points from the Multires Modifier but I cannot modify them. Here is my simple test of a Cube:

```
import bpy


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MULTIRES')
bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires", mode='CATMULL_CLARK')
bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires", mode='CATMULL_CLARK')

active_obj = bpy.context.active_object

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
multires_mesh = depsgraph.objects[active_obj.name].data

# test to modify
print(len(multires_mesh.vertices))  # It Will be 98 Points. Multires!
for v in multires_mesh.vertices:
    v.co[0] *= 2.0

#depsgraph.update()
active_obj.data.update()
```

But if you run this code no points will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MULTIRES')
bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires", mode='CATMULL_CLARK')
bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="Multires", mode='CATMULL_CLARK')

active_obj = bpy.context.active_object

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
multires_mesh = depsgraph.objects[active_obj.name].data

# test to modify
print(len(multires_mesh.vertices))  # It Will be 98 Points. Multires!
for v in multires_mesh.vertices:
    v.co[0] *= 2.0
    
bm2 = bmesh.new()
bm2.from_mesh(multires_mesh)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: It works, but it makes an Exception. Is it possible to make it without the Exception. Thank you a lot!

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But if I go to EditMode then ObjectMode then all multires will deformations disappear.
Or if i'll add "active_obj.data.update()" in the end of this code